# How do I launch an executable without opening Terminal?

Tags: macos, applescript

I've written a simple command-line executable file, and am trying to make it launch whenever I open its enclosing folder. I'm using a folder action that opens an AppleScript. So far, the AppleScript is:

```
    tell application "Finder"
        open document file "Feed the Beast Launcher" of folder "Feed The Beast" of folder "Desktop" of folder "Matthew" of folder "Users" of startup disk
    end tell
```

and the executable file is:

```
    export JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6/Home
    java -jar ~/Desktop/Feed\ The\ Beast/FTB_Launcher.jar
```

Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Jar Bundler.app to create a standalone app of your jar file and use something like

```
tell application "FTB_Launcher.app" to activate
```

to start the app.